# NSInvalidArgument exception when using #selector swift3

Tags: swift, swift3, selector, nstimer, unrecognized-selector

When I run the function

```
func makeSpriteShoot(bullets bulletInfo:MHBulletInformation,player playerSprite:SKSpriteNode){
    print("Foo")
    let shootTimer = Timer.scheduledTimer(timeInterval: bulletInfo.frequency, target: true, selector: #selector(shootBullet), userInfo: nil, repeats: true)
}
func shootBullet(){
    player.shootBullet(angle: 90)//player is a instance of a subclass of SKSpriteNode
}
```

I get the following exception+SIGABRT:

> terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: '-[__NSCFBoolean shootBullet]: unrecognized selector sent to instance ...

Both of the above functions are inside a subclass of SKScene running in Swift3.

Notably I do not get any compile time error unlike `#selector(test)`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have made mistake in setting `target` with `Boolean` value.

> `target` is the object to which to send the message specified by aSelector when the timer fires. The timer maintains a strong reference to target until it (the timer) is invalidated.

So simply set `target` to `self` if method exist in class where you scheduling `Timer`.

```
let shootTimer = Timer.scheduledTimer(timeInterval: bulletInfo.frequency, target: self, selector: #selector(shootBullet), userInfo: nil, repeats: true)
```